# Why Can I only download 51 images instead of 151 and Why no errors are showing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

Good Evening Everybody:

So i am web scraping an Indian Shoe Store Site and i get all 151 image links, but when i go to download them, i get only 51 with no errors. here is my code and Output

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import time

Bata = pd.read_csv("Batav1.csv")

Brand = Bata["Brand"].tolist()
Title = Bata["Title"].tolist()
Images = Bata["Img Links"].tolist()

r = requests.Session()

for b,t,i in zip(Brand,Title,Images):
    s = r.get(i).content
    with open("BataPics//Test//" + f"{t}-{b}.jpg","wb") as f:
        f.write(s)
    time.sleep(1)
```

[image: Pandas Data Frame]

CSV File link: (Google Drive)

[Csv File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jIiCzw_IWfqVkUuknP8ftTPQG_E4kIaL/view)

Comment: implement a counter in for loop to check whether it is actually running 151 times. I guess that u r getting only 51 results from `zip(Brand,Title,Images)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are duplicate combinations of the first two columns of the CSV file. This results in your code generating duplicate file names. Basically you are overwriting previously downloaded files.

In fact there should be 57 files, not 51.

Answer (score 0):

So i solved it as i was overwriting the files with same names, so i extracted the unique code from the image urls and got all 151 images :)